# Align to the right in visual block

Tags: vim, alignment

I would like to know how to align to the right in a visual block without changing the text before and the block.

I used this code till before:

```
:<C-U>'<,'>s/\%V\(.\{-}\)\(\s\{-}\)\%(\%V\@!\|$\)/\2\1/
```

However I noted that it doesn't work when after the visual block is only spaces.
(There has to be text after the visual block in order to make above code work)

Is there no way to align text to the right in a visual block whatever is written after the block?

Example:

```
text before +align text     text after 
text before   align text    text after
text before  align text     text after
text before     align text+ text after
```

What I want to do is select a block of text from `+` to `+` (see example above)
and align it to the right. Output must be:

```
text before      align text text after 
text before      align text text after
text before      align text text after
text before      align text text after
```

Above code does the job but it does not work when there is not something written after `align text` in every line.

Comment: A little before/after example would help. Because I don't know exactly what you are after my first idea would be `:right`.

Comment: :right will move all the text to the right. I added an example as you asked me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve the issue correctly handling all corner cases, I would use
the following function.

```
function! RightAlignVisual() range
    let lim = [virtcol("'<"), virtcol("'>")]
    let [l, r] = [min(lim), max(lim)]
    exe "'<,'>" 's/\%'.l.'v.*\%<'.(r+1).'v./\=StrPadLeft(submatch(0),r-l+1)'
endfunction
function! StrPadLeft(s, w)
    let s = substitute(a:s, '^\s\+\|\s\+$', '', 'g')
    return repeat(' ', a:w - strwidth(s)) . s
endfunction
```

Comment: when there is no text behind the block it gives the error E486: Pattern not found '\%V\\(.\{-}\\)\\(\s*\%V\s\\)\%V\@!'

Comment: @Remonn:  I cannot reproduce the problem.  Could you please show a particular test case leading to the error?

Comment: ib, yes. Please use the text in the example and remove everything after "align text" and trim the trailing spaces at end of line.

Comment: Seems the function fails while trying to align the second column right. https://gist.github.com/JikkuJose/cd6b2ab4d7bf2593eb94

Comment: @Jikku: How exactly does it fail? Does it produce a specific error?

Comment: Don't remember now; perhaps try the example I provided if you are using the code?

Answer (score 3):

I use this. Put the cursor before the text which should be aligned to right. Run `:Right`
How does it work:

1. `v0` Visualy select the text from current position to the beginning of the line
2. `d` Delete selected text and put into the buffer
3. `:right` Align the text on the right side of the cursor
4. `0` Put cursor to the first column
5. `gv` Visualy select same area which we deleted before
6. `p` Replace selection with deleted text

   `command! Right execute "normal v0d\<CR>:right\<CR>0gvp"`

Answer (score 1):

```
:'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V/\=printf("%*s", col("'>")-col("'<"), substitute(submatch(0), '^\s*\|\s*$', '', 'g'))
```

Comment: Kev, it does the job but something goes wrong when I select from "+" to the character left of the second "+" (the "t").

Comment: Ah.. it doesn't work. I see that it left a space before the end of every line in the block.

Comment: kev, that doesn't work when there is no extra space available (p.e. when "align text" is at the end of line).

Comment: kev, do you know how to increase the selection 1 character to the right in the commandline? (in order to select one more column at the right side)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by two regex:

```
:%s/+/ /g
```

This just replace every `+` to  `white-space`

```
:%s/\(\s\{2,}\)\(\w\+\s\+\w\+\)\(\s\{2,}\)/\1\3\2
```

This is just 3 groups to match the columns and spaces in between, then at replacement just change spaces from ahead to behind the desired column to align.